# Curl not displaying response to a HTTP request

Tags: curl, azure-functions

I am working through [Microsofts Azure's function training](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-serverless-logic-with-azure-functions/5-add-logic-to-the-function-app?pivots=javascript). I am running the code

`curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "x-functions-key: <your-function-key>" --request POST --data "{\"name\": \"Azure Function\"}" https://<your-url-here>/api/DriveGearTemperatureService`

with my function values; however, after pressing enter in command prompt, I only get a new line character. I have checked the function's logs and a request is not coming in for the function. I can run the function in Azure portal with no problems. I am using the Curl included with Windows 10. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `https://<your-url-here>/api/DriveGearTemperatureService` with the url you got from your function, not only the `<your-url-here>`. And delete the header  **x-functions-key**, because the url you got already includes the function-key.

For some reason your function-key was not passed from header parameter.

[image]